# Why Android networkInfo state CONNECTED is true, when the device displays no connection

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am developing an app for Android and I need to connect to a specific wifi. I manage to do that with this piece of code:

```
// Get the current wifi's ID if any, then disable it, to make sure the device will connect to the selected wifi
int currentWifiId = mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
mWifiManager.disconnect();
if (currentWifiId != -1) {
    mWifiManager.disableNetwork(currentWifiId);
}

// After disconnecting and disabling the previously connected wifi enable and reconnect to the new one
mWifiManager.enableNetwork(config.networkId, true);
mWifiManager.reconnect();
```

I have also implemented `BroadcastReceiver` with over riding the `onReceive` method. In `onReceive` I have the following code:

```
// Log
Log.i("onReceive", "called");

final String action = intent.getAction();

// If there was a state change in the network
if (action.equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

    if (networkInfo.getState() == State.CONNECTED) {
        // Log
        Log.i("onReceive", "CONNECTED to: " + mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSSID());

        // Check if we connected to the selected wifi
        if (mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSSID().equals("\"" + mAdapter.getItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition - 1) + "\"")) {
            finalizeConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

What happens (not always), when selecting the desired wifi, that in the `onReceive` method I get CONNECTED state equals to true, even if on my device I am still disconnected from all the wifis (the wifi icon is not showing on the top bar), then when it really connects to the desired wifi, I get two calls again in `onReceive` method with network state changed with CONNECTED state true.

This is how the log looks like after a case like this:

```
05-01 10:35:55.358    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ called
05-01 10:35:55.364    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ CONNECTED to: "SheepWeb_CA_5Ghz"
05-01 10:35:55.398    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ called
05-01 10:35:55.399    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ called
05-01 10:35:55.399    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ called
05-01 10:35:55.417    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ called
05-01 10:35:55.417    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ called
05-01 10:35:58.115    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ called
05-01 10:35:58.118    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ called
05-01 10:35:58.124    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ called
05-01 10:35:58.128    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ called
05-01 10:35:58.132    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ called
05-01 10:35:58.140    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ called
05-01 10:35:58.875    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ called
05-01 10:35:58.889    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ called
05-01 10:35:58.894    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ called
05-01 10:35:58.896    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ CONNECTED to: "SheepWeb_CA_5Ghz"
05-01 10:35:58.951    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ called
05-01 10:35:58.955    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ CONNECTED to: "SheepWeb_CA_5Ghz"
05-01 10:36:22.400    6720-6720/***.***********.********** I/onReceive﹕ called
```

Why is this? I want to call the `finalizeConnection()` method only if I am really connected to the desired wifi. Note, that this wifi might not have internet connection (which is not a problem in my case).

Comment: Did you tried 
ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null &&
                        cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) ?

Comment: Hi, this actually never gets true for me, calling it in onReceive next to my code.

Comment: I forgot to register ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION, that is why it was false for me, when I tried it. After trying it with the right intent registered, it worked. Unfortunately this one also produces sometimes the unwanted result, that it returns true for wifi connection is active even if it is not shown by the device.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. This is how I solved it.

In the on Receive:

```
if(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action))
{
    NetworkInfo netInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
    Log.d(TAG,"Network state changed action" + netInfo.getDetailedState().name());
    if(netInfo.getDetailedState().equals(NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTED))
    {
        Log.i("onReceive", "Connected");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution, but unfortunately it produces the same result. Thanks though!

Comment: @Silex Have you tried forgetting the network you are trying to connect to. Otherwise, what might happen is it will connect to _SheepWeb_CA_5Ghz_ and broadcast the intent and then your code will call disconnect, so it disconnects. And then, you reconnect to it...hence, connected again thus repeating the broadcast intent!

Comment: Calling disconnect to the currently connected wifi network and then disable it, doesn't solve this problem? Because this is what I am doing to make sure I don't reconnect to the previously connected wifi, instead of the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

I Had a similar Problem  in this

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Network[] networks = connectivityManager.getAllNetworks();
    NetworkInfo networkInfo;
    for (Network mNetwork: networks) {
     networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(mNetwork);
     if (networkInfo.getState().equals(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)) {
      return true;
     }
    }
   }
```

i Changed

```
 return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
```